# PyCharm thinks this RegExp has Duplicate character is characte class. Is it bug or not?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, unicode, pycharm

```
# Python3
r = re.compile(r"[\U0001f570\U0001f573\U0001f57a]")
```

This RegExp should find one of three emoji. Everything works correct, but PyCharm says:

> "Duplicate character \U0001f573 inside character class"
>
> "Duplicate character \U0001f57a inside character class"

If I change order, it says the same about 2nd and 3rd symbols, but never says about 1st one.

Is it a bug in PyCharm (maybe about about unicode surrogate pairs) or there is really something wrong with my RegExp?

UPDATE: Screenshot to be sure you get me right.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24172). It was closed in 2020-09.

Answer (score 1):

ran your code in my pycharm didn't get any errors:

> PyCharm 2017.1 Build #PY-171.3780.115, built on March 24, 2017
>
> JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b13 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by
>   JetBrains s.r.o Linux 4.4.0-75-generic

try updating the ide

Comment: It's not a runtime error. It is a IDE warning. PyCharm 2017.1.2
Build #PY-171.4249.47, built on April 26, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 3.13.0-37-generic

Comment: didnt get any warnings either. have you defined encoding at the top of your page?

Comment: It's python 3. # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- Should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you should be able to suppress the code inspection using:

```
 # noinspection Annotator
```

This is the suggested way by the `Code` -> `Inspect code...` dialog.

It does not work in my version of PyCharm but may work in yours.

> PyCharm 2018.3.3 (Community Edition) Build #PC-183.5153.39, built on January 9, 2019
>
> JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b26 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o >
>
> Windows 10 10.0